# In Bash, the `*` is no longer expanded before passing into a command?

Tags: bash, wildcards, csh

Is it different from C-shell?  I remember in C-shell, when we do

```
echo *
```

then the `*` is actually expanded by C-shell to all filenames in the current directory, so `echo` really doesn't need to do anything but to echo what is passed into it.  But in C-shell, we really need to do

```
find . -name '*item.js*'
```

so that even filenames such as `list-item.jsx` will be matched any level down the directory. So it can't "expand" the `*` of the current directory, because what if the current directory doesn't have such names.

However, in Bash, I found that we can just use

```
find . -name *item.js*
```

(it will go deep down into your folders).  So doesn't that mean

1. Bash doesn't expand the `*` into actual arguments before passing to a command, unlike C-shell?
2. Does that mean all commands running under Bash, such as `echo` has to take `*` and process it inside of the code of `echo`? But then what if you invoke C-shell and run `echo` -- then it is the same binary. Does that mean all commands must be able to handle `*` when its binary sees the `*` as the argument and must be able to handle it?

Comment: If there are no files in your current directory that match \*item.js\*, then the shell won't expand the glob, instead passing it along to find.

Comment: oh... then with `find`, we really should use single quotes: `'*item.js*'`, because, otherwise it depends on whether the current folder has that pattern... and it feels kind of probabilistic...

Comment: I closed this as a dupe of another question because while the questions aren't the same, the answer explains what you observed as well.